# interface for object with indexer

Tags: c#, object, indexing

I have an object. Can i try to iterate through the indices of this object somehow?

So for example:

```
object[] someObjects = new object[]
{
    "a string",
    new Position(5, 2, 1), // Position is indexed: position[0] -> 5
    10
};

foreach (object obj in someObjects)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.indexRange; i++)
    {
        obj[i] += 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make a class and be done with it. You could have written it in the time you wrote the question

Comment: the problem is that the Position class and also other classes are part of a library and a struct. I can't make a container class since it is not referenceable

Comment: Then you can create a new CustomPosition class which inherits from Position

Comment: You can test via reflection whether the type has an indexing operator and implements ienumerable, which would provide the index range

Comment: You're **using** `Position` in your code. In what way, then, are they "not referenceable"?

Comment: System.Object does not have an operator+() overload, so this code isn't going anywhere.  You *might* get lucky if you use `dynamic[]` instead.  A snippet is so supposed to show a realistic scenario, this one doesn't.